# Has the similarity relation of a tree-shaped labelled transition system have finite index?

Tags: transition-systems

Let $T$ be an infinite countable labelled transition system with the shape of a tree and let $\sim$ be its [similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation_(computer_science)) relation among nodes. Note that the alphabet of the labels is finite (hence the tree has finite branching). Let $T/\sim$ be its quotient w.r.t. the similarity relation, i.e. two nodes in $T$ are identified if they are similar. In general $T/\sim$ is a graph.

Is $T/\sim$ finite? If not in general, when is it finite?